# System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting charts are not displaying on IE8

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-8, charts

I created a chart using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting. The charts are displayed on google chrome and safari. But this is not visible on windows xp IE8. I really don't know how to fix this.

Here's a code snippet on my creation of charts.

```
<img src="/ConvertFiles/CreateActualsVsForecastChart/?actuals=@(thisMonth)&forecast=@(prevMonth)" />

public FileResult CreateActualsVsForecastChart(string actuals, string forecast, string chartName)
    {
        //IList<ResultModel> peoples = _resultService.GetResults();
        if (actuals.Equals(""))
            actuals = "0";
        if (forecast.Equals(""))
            forecast = "0";
        Chart chart = new Chart();
        chart.Width = 350;
        chart.Height = 400;
        chart.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(211, 223, 240);
        chart.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        chart.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
        chart.BorderlineWidth = 1;
        chart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
        chart.BorderlineColor = Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);
        chart.RenderType = RenderType.BinaryStreaming;
        chart.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
        chart.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All;
        chart.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.Normal;
        chart.Titles.Add(CreateTitle(chartName));
        chart.Legends.Add(CreateLegend());

        chart.Series.Add(CreateSeries4(new List<ChartKeyValue>()
            {
                new ChartKeyValue(){ Lable = "Forecast", Value = Convert.ToDouble(forecast), IsCurrent=true},
            }, SeriesChartType.Column, "Forecast", "pink"));

        chart.Series.Add(CreateSeries4(new List<ChartKeyValue>()
            {
                new ChartKeyValue(){ Lable = "Actual", Value = Convert.ToDouble(actuals), IsCurrent=true}
            }, SeriesChartType.Column, "Actual", "blue"));

        chart.ChartAreas.Add(CreateChartArea());

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        chart.SaveImage(ms);
        return File(ms.GetBuffer(), @"image/png");
    }
```

Any ideas on what's causing this to not be displayed on IE8? Thanks.

Comment: What is the error msg

Comment: There's no error message. It's just a broken image.

Comment: Then you code is probably working but some characters aren't escaped properly

Comment: Can you elaborate this? An example would be great!

Comment: Is this an IE 8 .PNG issue? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ba85dc5c-04b8-4bc1-a893-1c465bedf4be/internet-explorer-8-and-png-images-appears-a-red-cross-sign

Answer (score 1):

After going mad about this, I found that IE8 doesn't resize parent container when the chart is being created.
You need to put it explicitly in the DOM.
So for example:

```
<div>
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" SuppressExceptions="True" Width="1000px" Height="600px">
</asp:Chart>
</div>
```

will not render anything in IE8 (the div's width will be 0px), but:

```
<div style="width: 1100px">
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" SuppressExceptions="True" Width="1000px" Height="600px">
</asp:Chart>
</div>
```

will. Just set container width some pixel greater than chart width.